# When should I be responding to HTTP HEAD requests on my website

Tags: http, google-app-engine

My google app engine website is getting errors on the main url for HEAD requests because I am not accepting them.  According to [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4), the HEAD request is for ["testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4)

What should be my "normal" response to HEAD requests be?

I started accepting HEAD requests, to stop the errors from showing in my logs, but only on the main url.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement you `head` method(s) just like the `get` one(s), just skipping the writing of the body. You should do that for every URL that can be linked to, exactly because a well-behaved checker that's validating the links should use HEAD when it doesn't need the body.

Simplest is often to factor out the `get` functionality to a separate auxiliary method `_foo` that takes a boolean `needbody` argument -- `get` calls `self._foo(True)`, `head` calls `self._foo(False)`. `_foo`, if it sees its `needbody` argument is false, can bail out as soon as it has generated all headers (and must make sure it doesn't generate a body).

Comment: Another option, in webapp, is to define a base class that implements head by calling self.get then erasing the body. This is inefficient, of course, but lets you override it more efficiently on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @Nick What is the best way to erase the body?